# How to redirect to another page and specific div on button click in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I have one page called Page1 which have a button.

```
<button onclick="redirecttodivofotherpage(); "></button>
```

The other Page2 have 3 Div

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

I want to redirect to div3 on button click of Page1 button.
How to do it with controller or jquery.

Comment: you mean you want to scroll to your third div when button click in same page or in another page

Comment: yes i want to scroll automatically to div3 on button click

Comment: I added two ways to do it, try one of it, I think second one is nice. good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<button class="js-btn"></button>

$(function(){
    $(".js-btn").on("click",function(){
        window.location = "..../#div3";
    });
})
```

The string `"..../#div3"` represent the relative url of your page and at the end has a `#div3`. This way, using `window.location`, you would be redirected to the page you want and using `#div3` to the section you want.

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki You are welcome. I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with cookies. Setting a cookie with id you want to scroll, and then, when the new page is loaded, read the cookie and scroll to defined id. I used the very popular plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Check this sample solution Note: Click on Events to nav to the other page.

```
**http://plnkr.co/edit/hBJj69nP6kvrEuoCVw3k?p=preview**
```

Answer (score 3):

try this working demo, that will work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="click">Click Me</button>
 <div id="mydiv" style="border:2px solid black;width:800px;height:900px; background-color:orange; position:absolute;top:1000px;margin:20px;">
  hello anuradh
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").on('click',function(){
   window.location = "#mydiv";
  });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or else you can scroll it nicely like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="click">Click Me</button>
 <div id="mydiv" style="border:2px solid black;width:800px;height:900px; background-color:orange; position:absolute;top:1000px;margin:20px;">
  hello anuradh
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").on('click',function(){
   //window.location = "#mydiv";

    $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#mydiv").offset().top
        }, 2000);
   });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the second method will work without uri like "Home/Page1/" ?? onlu with Div name??

Comment: so you are doing the scrolling in same page, then does it a matter

Comment: no , i want to redirect to specific div of another page

Comment: then use the first method and give the `link`

Comment: yes, but first method does not provide smooth scrolling. it seems strange to be direct show the div.

Answer (score 2):

Use a window.location.hash to scroll to the element with the id

```
<button class="js-btn"></button>

$(function(){
    $(".js-btn").on("click",function(){
        window.location.hash = "#div3";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

`<a class="className">link</a>`

```
$(".className").on("click", function () {
    window.location = "yourPage.html#divId"; 
});
```